# Migrating an EJB project running on JBoss to Websphere Applicataion Server 7

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, websphere, migrate

I have a ***Java*** EJB project running on **JBoss** properly.However I have to migrate it to WAS. So I created an EAR then deployed it to **WAS**. After I tried to run this project on WAS i get this error:

> Error 500: javassist.util.proxy.MethodHandler,
>   [Servlet Error]-[javassist.util.proxy.MethodHandler]:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist.util.proxy.MethodHandler

How can I fix this error and run this project on WAS?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you use classes in your application not available on WebSphere, but on JBoss (namely `javassist`). Get the JAR containing those classes and add it to the EAR.

This is a common Java issue and not related to any application server, [`NoClassDefFoundError`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html). You must get all classes your application requires during runtime.

Edit: `javassist` information is available [here](http://www.jboss.org/javassist). Depending on your JBoss and WAS versions you must choose the right version.

Comment: Thanks a lot but how can i get these classes?